# iOS unwind CollectionView at didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

So i have created an app where users create custom workouts.
You enter the first view add a x number of rounds,than you click on a button in the tableview where you add rounds.That click opens another activity with a collectionview.

So the problem is here when i click on an element witch represents the exercise that needs to be in the round it sends me an empty result.By default if i add a value to that string it works.

I have noticed that the unwind happens before my didSelectItemAtIndexPath

```
import UIKit

class InsertWorkout: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet var InsertRoundTable: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!


    var RoundNumber : NSMutableArray = ["Round 1"]
    var RoundLabel : NSMutableArray = [""]
    var RoundExercise : NSMutableArray = ["add-1"]
    var RoundExerciseImages : NSMutableArray = ["providno"]

    var RoundNumber_Count=1
    var RoundNumber_Add_Counter=1

    var studentData : StudentInfo!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


    }

    //MARK: UIButton Action methods

    @IBAction func btnBackClicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    @IBAction func btnSaveClicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if(txtName.text == "")
        {
            Util.invokeAlertMethod("", strBody: "Please enter workout name.", delegate: nil)
        }
        else
        {
                let studentInfo: StudentInfo = StudentInfo()

                studentInfo.workout_name = txtName.text!

                studentInfo.workout_benefit_1=" CUSTOM "
                studentInfo.workout_benefit_2=" WORKOUT "
                studentInfo.workout_benefit_3=""
                studentInfo.workout_requiremnets="arsutech.com"
                studentInfo.workout_time="4min"

                let isInserted = ModelManager.getInstance().addWorkoutData(studentInfo)
                if isInserted {
                    Util.invokeAlertMethod("", strBody: "Workout added", delegate: nil)
                } else {
                    Util.invokeAlertMethod("", strBody: "Error while adding workout.", delegate: nil)
                }

            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        InsertRoundTable.endEditing(true)
    }


    //UITableView

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return RoundNumber.count

    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cell : InsertRoundCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("InsertRoundCell") as! InsertRoundCell
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("InsertRoundCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! InsertRoundCell;
        }
        let exerviseName = RoundNumber[indexPath.row]
        let exerciseLabels = RoundLabel[indexPath.row]
        let exerciseImage = RoundExercise[indexPath.row]
        let exerciseImage_Holder = RoundExerciseImages[indexPath.row]


        cell.insert_label_Round.text = exerviseName as? String
        cell.addWorkout_Label.text = exerciseLabels as? String
        cell.addExercise_Holder?.image = UIImage(named: exerciseImage_Holder as! String) as UIImage?

        cell.addWorkoutBut.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: exerciseImage as! String) as UIImage?, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        cell.addWorkoutBut.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.addWorkoutBut.addTarget(self, action: "logAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        return cell as InsertRoundCell

    }


    @IBAction func logAction(sender: UIButton){
         //self.RoundNumber.replaceObjectAtIndex(sender.tag, withObject: "Ezel")
         //let titleString = self.RoundNumber[sender.tag] as? String
         //Util.invokeAlertMethod("", strBody: titleString!, delegate: nil)
         self.InsertRoundTable.reloadData()
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ChoseExercise
        destinationVC.id=sender.tag
        RoundNumber_Count=sender.tag
    }

    @IBAction func unwinndChoseExercise(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){


        if let svc = segue.sourceViewController as? ChoseExercise{
            self.RoundLabel.replaceObjectAtIndex(RoundNumber_Count, withObject: "\(svc.exercise_label)")
            self.RoundExercise.replaceObjectAtIndex(RoundNumber_Count, withObject: "providno")
            self.RoundExerciseImages.replaceObjectAtIndex(RoundNumber_Count, withObject: "\(svc.exercise_image)")
            self.InsertRoundTable.reloadData()
        }
    }


    //Add Round
    @IBAction func addRound(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(RoundNumber_Add_Counter<12){
            RoundNumber_Add_Counter++
            self.RoundNumber.addObject("Round \(RoundNumber_Add_Counter)")
            self.RoundLabel.addObject("")
            self.RoundExercise.addObject("add-1")
            self.RoundExerciseImages.addObject("providno")
            self.InsertRoundTable.reloadData()

        }else{
        Util.invokeAlertMethod("", strBody: "This is the maximum number of rounds", delegate: nil)
        }

    }
}




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }



    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.exercisesNames.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellexercises_insert", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Insert_ExerciseCollectionViewCell

        cell.insert_exerciseImage?.image = self.exercisesImages[indexPath.row]
        cell.insert_exerciseLabel?.text = self.exercisesNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.insert_exercisesHardnessImg?.image = self.exercisesHardnessImg[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         exercise_label="\(exercisesNames[indexPath.row])"
         exercise_image="\(exercises_Exervise_Row_Names[indexPath.row])"
         dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how unwinding works:

First, put your IBAction unwind(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) in the vc where you intend to go back (presenter vc, InsertWorkout in this case).

Second, go to storyboard and choose the vc where you'll unwind from (collection view in this case) and ctrl-drag from the button/cell that causes the unwind (collection view cell in your case) to the exit button on top of that same vc and you should see a pop-up with your IBAction unwind method name under 'Selection Segue'.

Third, implement prepareforsegue in the current vc (collection vc in this case) to pass your data back.

```
class InsertWorkout
{
    IBAction func unwind(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        //use the data passed from prepare to update your ui or you can also communicate to the sender using segue.sourceVC
    }
}
class CollectionVC
{
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboadSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
        if segue.identifier == "whatever you put in storyboard for segue id" {
            if let inserWorkoutVC = segue.destinationViewController as? InsertWorkout {
                //pass the data here but don't attempt to update your destination's view ui!!, 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to send over a button click the id information and I'm facing problem when i use performSegueWithIdentifier with sending that data.Its kind of confuzing

Comment: did you do the proper connection in your storyboard

Comment: I mean from your button to the exit icon

Comment: and one more question, are you unwinding to the above VC or from it?

Comment: Its like this i have a button in my tableview than i click on it on opens an view that holds that collection view.After you click on it it should take you back to the prevous view and add that selected image to the round from which the button was clicked.So you have like x numbers of rounds that you can add and i send an id over those buttons

Comment: I think I get what you're trying to do, I'll edit my answer in a sec

Comment: So i need somehow my cellForItemAtIndexPath to do the process first than the unwindsegue to do its thing

Comment: Sorry i have managed to solve this here is the code from my current problem that i expalined you

Comment: wait, does the button unwind back to the vc or do you present another view when clicked?

Comment: View one you click on the button the it opens a vc with a collection view you go back and that data is added to that button from which it was clicked

Comment: how do you go back from the collection view, do you have a button that causes to go back or is it embedded in navigation controller?

Comment: i have connected my unwinndChoseExercise to the cell of the collectionview

Comment: you click on it and it shoudl add the data and send you back

Comment: Just edited my answer, its probably more general but I hope it helps you

Comment: just remember prepare for segue is called before the vc is setup so don't do any ui stuff there, just pass the data and update your ui in the IBAction unwind