# how to avoid circular segues in swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, segue

I have a project which has the following structure:

The user is presented with a login view controller, on successful login, a tab group is opened. One of the tabs is a profile tab. From within there, a user can click on a following or followers button.

Each of these buttons segue onto a list of users. From there each user is clickable and this leads onto a 'membersDetailed' controller. Within that controller, there is again a followers and following button. This again is clickable and leads to a list of users who are then clickable leading back to 'membersDetailed' again. So with the current set up, the user can keep going further and further in and memory is a concern for me.

How can I handle this is the most memory efficient way? Should I be programmatically popping controllers instead of using storyboard segues or what is the best approach?

I'm also noticing that when I navigate back along the chain the memory doesn't seem to reduce. Even though I am using a navigation controller.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Unwind Segue to go back or on the reverse direction

Comment: so where would I be using the unwind segues in my set up? When I click on profile > followers > membersDetailed > followers. I'd have an unwind on my membersDetailed controller back to followers? Can I then pass data to that screen?  Also, what happens from a user perspective here when using the default navigation back button?

Comment: I recently gave an answer for a similar question. explanation on how to use the unwind segue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33111176/3405387

Comment: To answer your question above, yes you can pass data back. You can do that either in prepare for segue or in the "go back" method that will have storyboard as a parameter